# Embed HTML/JS code on page and execute

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript that I embed and on a page like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="site.com/myscript.js"></script>
```

The code above should return a HTML snippet that can contain regular HTML, javascript content (inside `<script>` `</script>` tags and or also code like `<script src="other_sources.js" TYPE="text/javascript"></script>`

I'm using something like this to display the code on the page.

```
document.write('<div id="displayAd"></div');
document.getElementById("displayAd").innerHTML = "{code here}";
```

This places the content on the page but does not execute the script src or the script added on the code. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The script tag will give you javascript, not a mish-mesh of HTML content, javascript, and other script tags. You can use pure javascript to get what you want as long as you define the separate pieces. For example, your myscript.js might look something like this:

```
(function (win) {
    var MYAPP,
        adIndex = 0,
        srcIndex = 0,
        html,
        srcs;

    //helper function to load scripts
    //JavaScript Patterns book
    function require(file, callback) {
        var script = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0],
            newjs = document.createElement('script'),
            calledBack = false;

        if (typeof callback !== "function") {
            //noop
            callback = function () {};
        }

            // IE
        newjs.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (newjs.readyState === 'loaded' || newjs.readyState === 'complete') {
                newjs.onreadystatechange = null;
                if (!calledBack) {
                    callback();
                    calledBack = true;
                }
            }
        };

        // others
        newjs.onload = function () {
            if (!calledBack) {
                callback();
                calledBack = true;
            }
        };

        newjs.src = file;
        script.parentNode.insertBefore(newjs, script);
    }

    //variable for html content and external scripts
    win.MYAPP = win.MYAPP || {
        html: [],
        srcs: []
    };

    MYAPP = win.MYAPP;
    html = MYAPP.html;
    srcs = MYAPP.srcs;

    //Add some HTML content to MYAPP.html
    html.push('<div>AD CONTENT HERE</div>');
    html.push('<div>ANOTHER AD HERE</div>');

    //Other external sources that will be loaded async... Array of objects with file and optional callback to run
    //when loaded.
    srcs.push({file: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js', callback: DoWork});

    //Load the scripts
    for (srcIndex = 0; srcIndex < srcs.length; srcIndex++) {
        require(srcs[srcIndex].file, srcs[srcIndex].callback);
    }

    //Do stuff with HTML content
    var displayAd = document.createElement("div");
    displayAd.innerHTML = html[adIndex];
    adIndex = (adIndex + 1) % html.length;
    document.body.appendChild(displayAd);
    //Rotate Ads every 3 seconds.
    window.setInterval(function () {
        var len = html.length;
        if (len && adIndex <= len) {
            displayAd.innerHTML = html[adIndex];
            adIndex = (adIndex + 1) % len;
        }
    }, 3000);

    //Sample callback function to be executed after script is loaded
    function DoWork() {
        win.$(function () {
            win.alert('Jquery loaded');
        });
    }

}(window));
```

I tried to stick with a pure js implementation. MYAPP contains two properties of interest. An array of html content to be "shoved" into the dynamically created displayAd div, and srcs to contain an array of external scripts to include. You need to supply an optional callback in case you wanted to work with the script after it has been loaded (DoWork for example). Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uP6E4/) example.

There are libraries that might handle more of this nicely (like requirejs for example) to load external dependencies, but again wanted to provide a library agnostic approach.